# Is it possible to animate HTML <input> placeholder text change

Tags: javascript, html, input

I've been told that animating a change between showing and hiding the text, such as an alpha change is not possible.

Comment: What about animating the actual placeholder text change, e.g. from one string to another string?

Answer (score 2):

[**http://jsfiddle.net/qNmjw/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/qNmjw/1/)

When you have an input as such

```
<input type="text" placeholder="the placeholder">
```

you can wrap it in a `label` in order to "move" the placeholder text from the input to the label span:

```
<label class='placeholder'>
  <input type="text" placeholder="">
  <span>the placeholder</span>
</label>
```

I wrote a small jquery function that does this rearrangement for any input with a placeholder attribute defined.

If your input has the `required` attribute, then you can take advantage of the CSS [`invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ainvalid) selector and you don't need a `keyup` event. See here: [**http://jsfiddle.net/qNmjw/2/**](http://jsfiddle.net/qNmjw/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, well- kind of...
This should work on most the new browsers, and it uses vendor specific selectors. I would recommend to test it by yourself to make sure it covers your chosen browsers (& versions)...

Consider the HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="placeholder's text" />
```

With the next CSS:

```
input {transition:color 1s;}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:#0000ff;transition:color 1s;
}
input::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox */
    color:blue;transition:color 1s;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
    color:blue;transition:color 1s;
}
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#ff0000;}
```

Play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3g2J7/1/

Comment: its posible do this when input text change?